# Intellij IDEA почему пишет Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: intellij-idea

Не работает IntelliSense и прочее автодополнение, при этом билдится модуль исправно, у меня несколько директорий с проектами, используется gradle для билда

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + S --> Editor --> General --> Code Completion --> Autopopup code completion галка стоит?

Comment: @Владимир стоит, если выделяю именно как sources root не папку src а конкретный пакет то оно работает автодополнение , но sources root же должен быть src

Comment: Не решили проблему?